# Adding jquery validation to dynamically generated textboxes in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, model-view-controller

**I am using ASP.NET MVC framework for a form in which the textboxes are dynamically generated. I want to add jquery validation for all the textboxes for numeric entry. How do I do that?**

```
<table>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Submit", "Expenses", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "UploadForms" }))
    {
       @Html.AntiForgeryToken() 
    HtmlHelper.UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled = false;
    @Html.ValidationSummary(false, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    if (Model.ExpenseDetails != null && Model.ExpenseDetails.Count > 0)
    {
        int i = 0;
        int l_ExpHead = Model.ExpenseHeadDict.Count;
        int l_ExpDate = Model.ExpenseDateDict.Count;

            <thead class="thead-light">
                <tr>
                <th scope="col" style="width:15%">Expense Title</th>
                @for (int col = 0; col < l_ExpDate; col++)
                {
                        <th colspan="2" scope="col" style="width:15%">@Model.ExpenseDateDict[col].ToString()</th>
                }
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>

                @for (int row = 0; row < l_ExpHead; row++)
                {
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">@Model.ExpenseHeadDict[row].ToString()</th>

                    @for (int col = 0; col < l_ExpDate; col++)
                    {
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ExpenseDetails[i].ExpenseHead)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ExpenseDetails[i].DateOfExpense)
                        string l_UploadID = "Upload_" + i;
                        string l_AmountID = "Amount_" + i;
                        string l_Span = "Span_" + i;
                        <td>

                            @Html.TextBoxFor(o => o.ExpenseDetails[i].Amount, new { @id = @l_AmountID, @class = "form-control input-group", @style = "width:140px" , @placeholder = "Amount"})
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(o => o.ExpenseDetails[i].Amount, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })                         

                        </td>
                         <td>   
                             <span class="fa fa-plus input-group" onclick="document.getElementById('@l_UploadID').click(); ShowFileCountLabel('@l_UploadID','')"></span>
                        </td>
                        i++;
                    }
                </tr>


                }

            </tbody>


        }
    }
</table>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#UploadForms").validate();
        $("input").each(function () {
            $(this).rules("add", {
                number: true,
                messages: {
                    number: "Please enter a valid amount."
                }
            });
        });

    })
</script>
```

Expected result:
On submit button click, I want the validation message for the textboxes to be displayed if the user enters any non-numeric entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set type="number"

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(o => o.ExpenseDetails[i].Amount, new { @id = @l_AmountID, @class = "form-control input-group", @style = "width:140px" , @placeholder = "Amount",@type="number"})
```

Comment: Using  (@type="number") worked. Please suggest is it advised to use this method or jquery validation should be used?

Comment: They include built-in validation to reject non-numerical entries. The browser may opt to provide stepper arrows to let the user increase and decrease the value using their mouse or by simply tapping with a fingertip. I would like to prefer this method

Comment: this [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number) would be useful for you